# How to convert JavaBean contains List to Map in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

```
public class MyAgreementList {
    private String name;

    private List<MyAgreement> agreementList;

    public List<MyAgreement> getAgreementList() {
        return agreementList;
    }

    public void setAgreementList(List<MyAgreement> agreementList) {
        this.agreementList = agreementList;
    }


}
```

I want to convert MyAgreementList to Map,anyone can help me?
The result I want is that:the Map have two keys : name,agreementList,and the List value can not be lost

Is there any framework can support this?

Comment: the result like this:"agreementList" : [ {
      "productName" : null,
      "estiateRate" : null,
      "amount" : null,
      "arriveAmount" : null,
      "tips1" : null,
      "tips2" : null,
      "agreementNumber" : null
    } ]

Answer (score 0):

psudocode : iterate the list and get agreement id and add as key else maintain some counter for key.Hope this helps

```
for(MyAgreement mya : agreementList){
      map.put(mya.getId(),mya);
      //maintain a counter say counter
       //map.put(counter++,mya);
     }
```

Comment: The result I want is that:the Map have two keys : name,agreementList,and the List value can not be lost